# How to implement inheritance like "var obj = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(... ...)" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In OpenLayers, we can create a object by using the following syntax:

```
var obj = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(... ...);
```

How to define that inheritance? I know the prototype mechanism but I have no idea about how to implement this inheritance.

Comment: The line of code you posted has nothing to do with inheritance. Are you asking about how to create nested objects (`a.b.c`)?

Comment: `var OpenLayers = {Layer: {WMS: function() {...} } };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the each successive object like this:

```
var OpenLayers = {};
OpenLayers.Layer = {};
OpenLayers.Layer.WMS = function() {}
```

The whole thing could be defined in one javascript literal like this:

```
var OpenLayers = {
    Layer: {
        WMS: function() {}
    }
}
```

These are generally called namespace objects which are just containers for organizing groups of functions in a logical manner outside of the global namespace.  A "namespace object" is just a term used for this type of usage of a normal javascript object.

This has nothing to do with inheritance or the prototype mechanism - just plain javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve inheritance like this:

```
var obj = Object.create(Object name);
```